# Printing a text file which is stored line by line

Tags: c++

I trying to write a function which searches for an ID and prints the book name and author name. I have been able to match the ID, however not able to properly print the book and author name. Text file is stored as such:

```
ID
book name 
author name
```

Following is the code for my search function:

```
void searching() {
    string search, id, name;
    ifstream myfile("books.txt");
    bool found = false;
    string line;
    cout << "\nEnter ID to search : ";
    cin >> search;
    int srchlen = search.length();
    if(myfile.is_open()) {
        while(getline(myfile, line)) {
            id = line.substr(0, srchlen);
            if(id == search) {
                found = true;
                break;
            } else {
                found = false;
            }
        }

        if(found == true) {
            name = line;
            cout << "ID\tNAME\tAUTHOR\n";
            cout << name;

        } else {
            cout << "ID doesnt exist";
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how the text file looks like (there is a blank line between each book):

```
98
crime and punishment
Dostoevsky

70
The Da Vinci Code
Dan Brown
```

Comment: So it the line `"ID book_name author_name"` (whitespace separated?)

Comment: Make a [mcve] and include a few lines from the real data file as a code block.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin sorry i am bit new to programming, by whitespace separated u mean they are stored in a different line in the text file. If so then yes they are.

Comment: @TON_618 Copy a few book titles and put them in the question.

Comment: No, *whitespace* just means `space`, `tab` or `newline` for most purposes (there is the vertical tab and one or two others you rarely see). So "Is all that stuff on one line for 1-book or 3-speaate lines?" `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Information about 1 book is stored in 3 separate lines

Answer (score 2):

So there's a logical flaw in your code that makes it harder to do what you want. The book data is stored on three separate lines, but your code reads one line at a time. Logically you should be reading three lines at a time. By doing this you'll have all the information available for one book at the same time.

Like this

```
string id, title, author;
while (getline(myfile, id) && getline(myfile, title) && getline(myfile, author)) {
    string blank;
    getline(myfile, blank); // skip the blank line between books
    id = id.substr(0, srchlen);
    if (id == search) {
        found = true;
        break;
    } else {
        found = false;
    }
}
if (found == true) {
    cout << "ID\tNAME\tAUTHOR\n";
    cout << id << ' ' << title << ' ' << author << '\n';;
} else {
    cout << "ID doesnt exist";
}
```

Note that reading the blank line is not part of the while condition. We don't want not to consider a book just because it wasn't followed by a blank line. This might happen at the end of the file for example.

Comment: What if you declare `found = false` in the beginning and trigger it when the given ID is matched? It'll be better than writing `found = false` again and again.

Comment: It always prints ID doesn't exist

Comment: Well something going wrong with the searching .Since I don't have your input file I wasn't able to test the code. The principle is correct though, read the data three lines (or one book) at a time.

Comment: Maybe there are blank lines between the books, or something like that you didn't mention.

Comment: @TON_618 OK so apparently there are blank lines, these details are important. So since you effectively have one book stored in **four** lines you should read four lines at a time. See the editted code.

Comment: it doesn't even give an output anymore.

Comment: yes there is a blank line between each book. my text file is exactly as shown in the question.

Comment: @TON_618 I've updated your question with the info you've given here in the comments. In the future, you should preferably update the question yourself when you get requests to clarify the problem.

Comment: @TON_618 Well there's some other problem. I'm sorry but at some point you have to take repsonsibility for your own code. And note that the change I made should not make the difference between wrong output and no output. You've made some mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

To make it easier to deal with the data, I recommend putting the information about a book into a class (`struct`) and to add operators for reading/writing one book at a time from/to an `istream`/`ostream`.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <string>

struct Book {
    std::string id;
    std::string title;
    std::string author;
};

// operator for reading one book title from any istream
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Book& b) {
    std::getline(is, b.id);
    std::getline(is, b.title);
    std::getline(is, b.author);

    // ignore the blank line between books in the file:
    is.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    return is;
}

// operator for writing one book title to any ostream
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Book& b) {
    return os << b.id << '\n' << b.title << '\n' << b.author << "\n\n";
}

int main() {
    std::string search;

    std::cout << "\nEnter ID to search : ";
    std::cin >> search;

    if(std::ifstream myfile("books.txt"); myfile) {
        Book book;

        // read one book at a time from the stream using the added
        // operator>>
        while(myfile >> book) {
            if(book.id == search) {
                // book found, write it to cout using the added
                // operator<<
                std::cout << book;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's another improved way to do it.

Comment: +1 I just got to know more works about I/O manipulators. I really appreciate the coding method of this question. So beautiful!

Answer (score 1):

By taking some advantages of C++ such as vector, you can make the code easier:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

const char *fileName = "books.txt";

// structure of the file
struct book {
    int ID;
    std::string author;
    std::string bookName;
};

int main(void) {
    std::ifstream file(fileName); // to read the file
    std::vector<book> vec;        // to find the content required
    int ID;                       // the ID to find
    book temp;                    // temporary 'book' to insert in vector
    bool found = false;

    // if the file was unable to open
    if (!file.is_open()) {
        std::cout << "Unable to open the file." << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // getting the content of the file
    while (file >> temp.ID >> temp.bookName >> temp.author)
        vec.push_back(temp);

    std::cout << "Enter the ID to find: ";
    std::cin >> ID;

    // matching the IDs

    for (size_t i = 0, len = vec.size(); i < len; i++)
        // prints when ID asked to show is present in the file
        if (vec[i].ID == ID) {
            std::cout << "ID: " << vec[i].ID << " | Author: "
                      << vec[i].author << " | Name: " << vec[i].bookName;
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    if (!found)
        std::cout << "The ID does not exist." << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Supposing the `books.txt` contains:

```
// FORMAT: ID _ Book _ Author
10 BookABC John
20 BookXYZ Ben
30 CodingBook Rock
```

Then the output would be something like:

```
Enter the ID to find: 30
ID: 30 | Author: Rock | Name: CodingBook
```

Comment: I have to solve to this question for my uni, unfortunately I can't use vectors as it's not in my course yet and also can't fully changed my code as it has other functions for adding, deleting, viewing and updating records.

Comment: @TON_618 You never defined any constraints in your question. So, anyone would answer up to any limits.

Comment: Note: `file >> temp.ID >> temp.bookName >> temp.author` will probably not work since `author name` and `book title` contain spaces.

Comment: @TedLyngmo and they must not contain whitespaces or they'll be understood separated contents. But you can although write something like `JohnDoe`, `BookABC`.

Comment: @RohanBari Yes, I see. That might be problematic if OP isn't allowed to change the file format though.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Obviously, but this code works as the file format given in the question.

Comment: @RohanBari Oh, I don't find that information in the question. It seems to say `ID` `\n` `book name` `\n` `author name` `\n` the way I read it.